# Python: I want to decorate a MethodType attribute without changing the attribute type to FunctionType

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

I want to implement the following functionality without changing type(testObject) to FunctionType:

```
import functools

class TestClass(object):
    def speak(self):
        print 'My Name is Test'

def hello_decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def hello_func(*args , **kwargs):   
        print 'Hello World'
        return func(*args , **kwargs)

    return hello_func

testObject = TestClass()

preDecoratedSpeak = hello_decorator(getattr(testObject , 'speak'))
setattr(testObject , 'speak' , preDecoratedSpeak)

testObject.speak()

print type(testObject.speak)
```

Output:

```
Hello World
My Name is Test
<type 'function'>
```

Is there a way to decorate a method while keeping the the method a MethodType instantiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use a third-party module such as `wrapt`, then you can manually unwrap and wrap the function in the decorator. In fact, you can write a decorator that can be applied to a decorator to do this automatically.

```
def accepts_method(decorator):

    @functools.wraps(decorator)
    def decowrapper(func):
        if hasattr(func, "im_func"):
            return type(func)(decorator(func.im_func), func.im_self, func.im_class)
        else:
            return decorator(func)

    return decowrapper
```

Now you can just decorate your decorator:

```
@accepts_method
def hello_decorator(func):
    # etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a cool fix. I think i should be able to use wrapt, but it'll be nice to not have to rely on it.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately `functools.wraps` has a few shortcomings in python 2, many of which are fixed in python3.

Try using [wrapt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wrapt) instead:

> The wrapt module focuses very much on correctness. It therefore goes way beyond existing mechanisms such as `functools.wraps()` to ensure that decorators preserve introspectability, signatures, **type checking abilities** etc. The decorators that can be constructed using this module will work in far more scenarios than typical decorators and provide more predictable and consistent behaviour.

Comment: Very useful to know. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that.

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't seem like wrapt.decorator preserves type.

Comment: It is technically impossible to preserve the type when wrapping an object with a proxy of a different type. Using ``type()`` will always return the type of the wrapper. A correctly working proxy wrapper will though preserve the operation of ``isinstance()`` and it should be used for type comparisons and you generally should not be comparing against ``type()`` directly.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy if you understand how the mechanism of the function descriptor works. No additional modules involved, just the Python magic.

Contrary to the intuitive perception, Python internally does not have a list of bounded methods for every instantiated object. Instead it stores a list of instantiated objects and a list of unbounded methods (the class) that simply contains function descriptors. Whenever you reference a bounded method in the code (and I really mean EVERY TIME you do) the interpreter associates the object instance with the unbounded method function and... voilà, you get a bounded method.

For basic information:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods

Knowing that every function is in fact a function descriptor, to get a bounded method you simply have to do yourself that association with the instanced object. The same way Python does:

```
bounded_method = unbounded_method.__get__(obj, None)
```

In fact you could accomplish the same and get a bounded method by simply doing:

```
import types

bounded_method = types.MethodType(unbounded_method, obj)
```

So in your decorator code, instead of just returning the decorated function, you should do the following:

```
import functools
import inspect

def hello_decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args , **kwargs):   
        ...

    if inspect.ismethod(func):
        return wrapper.__get__(func.__self__, None)
    else:
        return wrapper
```

More unrelated info about how to do basic magic with function descriptors:

```
class Klass():
    def method(*args, **kwargs):
        ...

# Klass.method is just a function descriptor, not bounded to anything.

class_method  = Klass.method.__get__(Klass, None) # -> Class method bounded to the class.
static_method = Klass.method.__get__(None, Klass) # -> Static method, not bounded to the class
                                                  #    (you get the exact same function, in fact).
instance = Klass()
instance_method = Klass.method.__get__(instance, None)   # -> Method bounded to the instance.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but why do you use `setattr` and `getattr` instead of directly decorating it like this:

```
TestClass.speak = hello_decorator(TestClass.speak)
```

or directly in the class:

```
class TestClass(object):
    @hello_decorator
    def speak(self):
        print 'My Name is Test'
```

both keep the function type `<type 'instancemethod'>`

Is there any reason behind your use of `getattr` and `setattr` on the actual instance? Instead of overwriting methods of an instance a subclass might be more appropriate.

Comment: Because I need to be able to wrap all of the methods in an object without manually adding those lines for every method.